# Debugging Vaadin/Spring Boot and embedded Tomcat server

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I recently decided to give Vaadin a try.  I went to their site and it constructed a download of Vaadin 24.0.4/Spring Boot 3.0.5/Embedded Tomcat.

Looking at the pom.xml file it provided, I see:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5796</jvmArguments>
                <wait>500</wait>
                <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I build the project using the command specified in README.md:

```
mvnw clean package -Pproduction
```

Then I start the server using the command specified in README.md:

```
java -jar target/mrpc-admin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I want to attach to Tomcat from IntelliJ to debug.  I thought the following debug configuration would allow me to do so:

[image]

This, however, results in the error message:

```
Error running 'DebugMrpcAdminEmbedded': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5796): 
java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"
```

I'm obviously missing something, but don't know what.

Comment: maven configuration, you mentioned, takes effect when you start application via something like `mvn spring-boot:run` or `mvn spring-boot:start`, since you are starting application via CLI you need to provide debugger parameters to `java`, i.e.: `java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5796 -jar target/mrpc-admin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: Please post and accept an Answer with your found solution to assist posterity.